# How to extract string between two strings using java Pattern

Tags: java

I have a string /subscription/ffcc218c-985c-4ec8-82d7-751fdcac93f0/subscribe from which I want to extract the middle string /subscription/<....>/subscribe. I have written the below code to get the string

```
String subscriber = subscriberDestination.substring(1);
int startPos = subscriber.indexOf("/") + 2;
int destPos = startPos + subscriber.substring(startPos + 2).indexOf("/");
return subscriberDestination.substring(startPos, destPos + 2);
```

Gives back ffcc218c-985c-4ec8-82d7-751fdcac93f0

How can I use java Pattern library to write better code?

Comment: Define 'better'.

Comment: No it doesn't. It prints ffcc218c-985c-4ec8-82d7-751fdcac93f. Without the last character.

Comment: Why would you want to use `java Pattern library`? Do you expect any performance gain? I doubt you'll get some by using `java Pattern library`. But I recommend to profile it to be absolute sure about it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to use a regular expression, a simple way would be:

```
return subscriber.replaceAll("/.*/([^/]*)/.*", "$1");
```

- `/.*/` is for the `/subscription/` bit
- `([^/]*)` a capturing group that matches all characters until the next `/`
- `/.*` is for the `/subscribe` bit

And the second argument of `replaceAll` says that we want to keep the first group.

You can use a `Pattern` to improve efficiency by compiling the expression:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("/.*/([^/]*)/.*"); ///store it outside the method to reuse it

Matcher m = p.matcher(subscriber);
if (m.find()) return m.group(1);
else return "not found";
```

Comment: Carefull that regex `.*` is greedy, so the first `.*` will consume as many "/" as possible. So it will basicly take the value just before the last "/". The initial code was usin the value after the first "/" instead. No difference here, since only 2 "/" are used. (after he consume the first one)

Comment: @AxelH Agreed - I had originally put a `?` but decided to remove it to stick to the question and make the answer a bit simpler.

Answer (score 1):

5c from me. I recommend to use `Pattern` for extracting substring with known format:

```
public final class Foo {
    private static final Pattern PATTERN = Pattern.compile(".*subscription\\/(?<uuid>[\\w-]+)\\/subscribe");

    public static String getUuid(String url) {
        Matcher matcher = PATTERN.matcher(url);
        return matcher.matches() ? matcher.group("uuid") : null;
    }
}
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/nPgUbD/1)

Answer (score 0):

Performance can be improved by:

1. not creating a `substring`s.
2. Also `indexOf(..)` with a `char` should be faster than with `String`

   ```
   final int startPos = subscriberDestination.indexOf('/',1) + 1 ;
   final int destPos = subscriberDestination.indexOf('/',startPos+1);
   return subscriberDestination.substring(startPos, destPos );
   ```

About useing the `java Pattern library`:
Do you expect any performance gain? I doubt you'll get some by using java Pattern library. But I recommend to profile it to be absolute sure about it.

Comment: The original question has a wrong character count. You must have relied on it, because you transferred the mistake to your answer.

Comment: @Gonen I: I didn't check that because the question was not about an error in the result. I think I fixed that now (but feel free to edit my answer if it is still wrong.

Comment: "_How can I use java Pattern library to write better code?_"

Comment: @AxelH: Since *better* is not yet defined in the question, I wrote this answer about how to improve performance in case of object-creation and speed.